# IcCube - Leaves in Pivot table

Tags: pivot, parent-child, iccube

If I have a parent-child-dimension, whose data I show in the IcCube/PivotTable and I want to show the leaves only (with descendants([categories].[categories].[All-M],,leaves)), those leaves are shown hierarchically. So a level5 leave of one category is suddenly the parent of a level6 leave of the next category.

Is there a way to "flatten" this tree, so that those leaves are all shown on one level and not sorted in the tree wrongly?

EDIT:
Here is a query:

```
SELECT
NON EMPTY { [Measures].[group_quality] } ON COLUMNS,
NON EMPTY { TopCount(descendants([categories].[categories].[Level$0].[Portal],,leaves),30,[Measures].[revenue_potential]) } ON ROWS
FROM [Cube]
```

[image]

All categories in the picture are leaves, so none of them has any children.

Comment: Could you please provide some screenshots and example of request to cube?

Comment: I edited my first post, to show my problem a little better.

Comment: @ulrich, is there an easy way to get this hierarchy so we can test (in-memory data source) ?

Comment: You can use the data from your parent/child example: 
http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/user_guide/schemas_cubes/dim_parentchild.php. 
With the statement 

select [Measures].[value] on 0,
descendants([countries].[countries].[World],,leaves) on 1 
from [Cube]

France, Spain and Switzerland will be shown as children of Asia...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As workaround for that case you can use simple CSS dirty-hack.

1) First of all under **Widget** option tab of your widget you should set **Hide icons** to yes.

2) After this, to avoid collision with other Pivot Tables, add custom CSS class

[image: Custom CSS class]

3) Add these styles to **Report CSS**.

```
.pt-flattened .pt-hcont{
    margin-left: 0 !important    
}
```

Comment: It is really dirty, but it works :) But I still hope, that there is an MDX option, so I would wait a little, before I mark this as resolved...

Comment: Apparently there is no MDX way. So I mark your answer as correct. Thank you very much :)